# Dealing with input in C

Tags: c, input, scanf, fgets, getchar

A brief question really, looking for, wondering about, and asking for any tips for what the best way is to handle this type of input:

```
 word word
 word word word word
 word word word
 word word
```

whereby the number of words on each line is totally random, and each separate word can be added to some data structure, like a linked list or tree for example.

Fgets each line and parse? Getchar()? Any clues?

Comment: What is the likelihood of malicious input?  Could you get a word that is over 1 KiB long, for example?  What happens to punctuation?

Answer (score 2):

Reading one line at a time with `fgets` seems like the best option here. Then just use `strtok` or something similar to split by empty space and iterate over the result.

Comment: Be aware that `strtok()` destroys its input as it processes it.  It is also not thread-safe, and you have to be sure that no other function that you call from your parser uses `strtok()`, and that no function that calls your parser uses `strtok()`.  The condition on functions called is usually not too onerous; in library code, though, the second condition (no calling function also using `strtok()`) is not enforceable.

Comment: Is there another way you would recommend, I'm not really comfortable with strtok

Comment: @user1048116: strtok_r is the thread-safe version. Anyway, in your situation, I don't think that you need to worry about what Jonathan Leffler pointed out.

Comment: Agreed; for the immediate purpose at hand, `strtok()` will probably be adequate.  But it is as well to know about the weaknesses in tools you are using so as not to get bitten later.