# What is the meaning of unsafe in C++?

Tags: c++, strtok

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is strtok() Considered Unsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999418/why-is-strtok-considered-unsafe)

I have just noticed a warning (using Visual Studio) that strtok is unsafe, and strtok_s is not. Why is it unsafe and what is unsafe?

First part of my question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999418/why-is-strtok-considered-unsafe) but what is the meaning of unsafe and what are the problems and possible problems related to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strtok is not thread-safe. If two or more threads call strtok at the same time, the results will be undefined. I am reproducing here an answer by another user,  Jonathan Leffler:

> Be aware that strtok() destroys its input as it processes it. It is
>   also not thread-safe, and you have to be sure that no other function
>   that you call from your parser uses strtok(), and that no function
>   that calls your parser uses strtok(). The condition on functions
>   called is usually not too onerous; in library code, though, the second
>   condition (no calling function also using strtok()) is not
>   enforceable.

The response was given to this question: [Dealing with input in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467405/dealing-with-input-in-c/8467419#8467419)

Comment: It's worse than that, if two or more threads call `strtok` at the same time on *different* strings, the results are undefined. The reason is that `strtok` "remembers" what string you last called it on, so that you can pass a null pointer when you call it again. `strtok` cannot possibly be implemented in a thread-safe way.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Thanks, I edited to remove the "same" part.